# Return from function upon condition met in map

Tags: rust

Is there a way I can use map such that if a certain condition is met I can return an error? The reason is that i'm trying to implement the trait `FromStr` for my struct `BigNum`:

```
impl FromStr for BigNum {
    fn from_str(s: &str) -> Result<BigNum, BigNum::Err> {
        let filter_vec = t_num.chars().
            map(|a| match a.to_digit(10) {
                Some(x) => { x },
                None    => { /* return from function with Err */ }
            });                                                                                     
    }
}
```

Is this possible to do? Or should I simply iterate over the `chars()` myself and return an error upon reaching a `None`? Just wondering if there's an easy way to break out of `map` and return from the function

Comment: Did you try `return Err(..whatever..)`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Two key pieces of information will be useful here:

1. Iterators operate one item at a time, so iterator adaptors will only be executed while something is consuming the iterator.
2. [`FromIterator`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.FromIterator.html) (which powers `Iterator::collect`) is implemented for `Result` as well.

Since you didn't provide a [MCVE](/help/mcve), I made up sample code that can actually compile:

```
fn foo(input: &[u8]) -> Result<Vec<u8>, ()> {
    input.iter().map(|&i| {
        if i > 127 {
            Err(())
        } else {
            Ok(i + 1)
        }
    }).collect()
}

fn main() {
    let a = foo(&[1,2,3,4]);
    let b = foo(&[200,1,2,3]);
    println!("{:?}", a);
    println!("{:?}", b);
}
```

If you stick a `println!` in the `map` body, you can see that no numbers are processed after the 200.